# What's causing this forced redirect?

Tags: apache, http, .htaccess, redirect, webserver

I do not have root access to the site site.com but I have access to a subdomain me.site.com

I add an index.php (or any file and or folder for that matter) to the root folder (public_html) of this subdomain but everytime I try to go to me.site.com/index.php I get redirected to www.site.com

The .htaccess file in this subdomain is currently blank.

Why might this be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that .htaccess in subdomain folder can't override the .htaccess in root, and at the moment the .htaccess in your root folder is current affecting the subdomain, in which it redirects all visits to the subdomain to root. Imagine that .htaccess from your subdomain folder redirect visits to the directory itself and .htaccess from root also redirects visits to subdomain back to the root itself, that's gonna be a mess.

Well, that's what I think about it in my opinion. Have you tried contacting the one who own root folder to consider about this?

Comment: I thought .htaccess files in the subdomain have higher priority?